# Allure-CSharp Automation NUnit Playwright

Tags: nunit, playwright, allure

I'm trying to determine if there's a possibility to automate the execution of allure-csharp with playwright programmatically via a web api call or cron job outside of test explorer. Furthermore, I would like to still develop tests and be able execute them from within test explorer as well; meaning, the testing team could develop tests using c# and run within test explorer and then on deploy, said tests would be executed in a containerized environment nightly via a cron job. The other wrinkle would be that the test job class library would live in a different namespace and be refenced by the api/cron job.

Granted, with very limited background using the library, I'm able to build the test in test explorer, pull in some key vault env. references in the SetUpFixture and get that working. When I try to use the same tests in an api project and execute programmatically, it seems like fixtures and other expected attributed workflow sequences are not firing as expected. My suspicion is I'm think about this all wrong and I should probably be using allure commons in the api/cron approach to setup the tests correctly, if it's even possible.

When attempting the above, allure-csharp attributes and don't seem to be honored thus the fixture, startup etc are all bypassed/ignored.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.